# Make select list same height as text box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, navbar

I am trying to make the filter to the left of my text box exactly the same height as the text box and a smaller width; exactly like in this picture

[image]

**My code and current search box looks like this:**

[image]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <form action="#" method="get" id="searchForm" class="input-group">

            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                <select name="search_param" id="search_param" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="username">Username</option>
                    <option value="email">Email</option>
                    <option value="studentcode">Student Code</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
        </form><!-- end form -->
    </div><!-- end col-xs-8 -->
</div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Comment: We really need to see your css definition(s) as well.

Comment: @William_Wilson He's using Bootstrap, and I don't see any custom classes, so we really don't need them as there are available on Bootstrap's website.

Comment: Ahh, I must have missed that tag, I was worried about global definition conflicts, but clearly that wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS is off because you're using a `<select>` element as a `<button class="dropdown-toggle">`. Change your HTML to the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <form action="#" method="get" id="searchForm" class="input-group">

        <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
          <button id="search_condition" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">All <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <input name="search_param" value="all" type="hidden">
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="option_select" data-value="all"><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li class="option_select" data-value="username"><a href="#">Username</a></li>
            <li class="option_select" data-value="email"><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li class="option_select" data-value="studentcode"><a href="#">Student Code</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term..." type="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </span>
      </form><!-- end form -->
    </div><!-- end col-xs-8 -->
  </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Replace your `<select>` with a button that toggles a dropdown with a list of options, each with an attr `data-value=""` that would match the value of an option in the select. This fixes the CSS issue, but your need some custom JavaScript to handle the selection of an option:

```
$(".option_select").on("click", function(){
  $("input[name=search_param]").val($(this).attr("data-value"));
  $("#search_condition").html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

What this will do is set the label of the button to that of the option, as well as set a hidden `<input>` element's value to that of the selected option.

Here's a working example as well:

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/8b4hBepG71)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <form action="#" method="get" id="searchForm" class="input-group" >

            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                <select name="search_param" id="search_param" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle  form-control" style="width:150px;" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="username">Username</option>
                    <option value="email">Email</option>
                    <option value="studentcode">Student Code</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default form-control" type="submit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
            <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button> -->
        </form><!-- end form -->
    </div><!-- end col-xs-8 -->
</div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```